# about CustomDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, customdialog

I should make a list of clickable items. I wrote text for now. How do I make them clickable? Sorry but I just started to program in Android. Can you help me with the code?

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog 
{
    public CustomDialog(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.privacy_popup);

        TextView text = ((TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.text));
        text.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>item<b>"));
        //text.setText("Privacy");

        TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        text2.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>item2<b>"));

        TextView text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3);
        text3.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>item3<b>"));

        TextView text4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text4);
        text4.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>item4<b>"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well firstable i would suggest you using [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) if it possible, but anyway it's really easy to extends a Dialog, you might want to check [Custom Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) from the official Android guide.

Comment: There are no lists on this site

Answer (score 0):

If you are forced to use TextView elements, you can implement the TextView `onClickListener` listener as this:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO : do something

    }
});
```

Comment: I would like to put a menu clickable

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have to extend `Dialog` and create a custom dialog; an `AlertDialog` provides all the functionality you're looking for. Below is nothing more than a copy paste from the [Dialog topic](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog) on the developer website.

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

This will result in:

[image: AlertDialog showing list of options]

Swap out above `builder.setItems(...)` for:

```
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { ... } );
```

to add a radio button with each option, or:

```
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() { ... } );
```

for checkboxes.

[image: AlertDialog showing list of single choice options (with radio button)]

Comment: I need to do a dialog not a alertdialog

Comment: Why? If only you would elaborate a bit more on the specifics we would be able to help you out better. My answer is perfectly sound for "a list of clickable items", and so could a dozen other solutions be...